# Which algorithms are worth to learn or recall on preparation to Java developer interview?

Tags: java, algorithm

I know that is `Collections.sort()` method in Java but I think quicksort is worth to remember and try. 
My work target is general Java: web, database access, integration, not game developer, scientific application or another one that depends on advanced algorithms.
Which algorithms should I learn to pass without stress Java developer interview?

Comment: "What knowledge should I be able to successfully fake during an interview to get a job that I can't do?" ... Sorry, but this is what those questions all boil down to: learn to do the job you're applying for. That should prepare you pretty well for any interview.

Comment: If on a job interview they'd asked me of a particular method to remember, I'd probably rejected their offer.

Answer (score 3):

[Fizz Buzz](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest)

I usually don't care, if a developer knows the basic algorithms by heart. I do care, if he is capabale of understanding requirements and translating them in correct, testable and understandable pieces of code.

Ah, and I do care if he knows how to implement the most common design patterns. And he should know when and how to use collections, threads and - `String#split` - it's amazing how many "developers" don't know how to read and process a simple `csv` file.

Comment: @bbd - what was easy, the test or the answer? ;-)

Comment: question and solution in Fizz Buzz

Answer (score 0):

Although I fully agree with Joachim comment, I would go for : collection selection. This is not an algorithm per se, but rather a good view of which collection is good for which purpose :

- sorted content with constant lookup time ? `TreeSet` !
- mapped data with memorization of insertion order ? `LinkedHashMap` !

using that, and some knowledge of design patterns behind collections, you will far too often reply to algorithms questions using the knuth answer (or the subtle variation : as long as Sun developpers implemented it correctly, I only have to choose wisely).